# Using general comment character used in programming languages

Tags: regular-expressions, highlighting, comment, highlight-chars

I am using `highlight-regexp` with a regexp pattern that includes the elisp comment characters `;;`.  How can I extend the pattern so that it adequately handle the general comment character for each language?

```
 (highlight-regexp
   "^;;\s+\\(\\[.+\\]\\).*$" 'kmface 1))
```

I have found `comment-start` but do not know how to use it in the regexp

```
"^;;\s+\\(\\[.+\\]\\).*$"
```

Have started with `format` to try getting two comment characters next to each other to construct a `regexp`.

```
(let ((fm (format "%s%s" comment-start comment-start)))
    (message "fm: %s" fm))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the [same question on help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-12/msg00359.html).  [Thibaut Verron gave you the answer there.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-12/msg00420.html)  Repeating it here, for the benefit of others:

Use **`\s<`** to match the comment-start character, whatever it may be in the current mode. If you want two successive comment-start chars, use **`\s<\{2\}`**.

So your example would be:

```lisp
(highlight-regexp "^\\s<+\\(\\[.+\\]\\).*$" 'kmface 1))
```

Or if you want only two comment-start chars, as you later stipulated, then:

```lisp
(highlight-regexp "^\\s<\\{2\\}\\(\\[.+\\]\\).*$" 'kmface 1))
```

(You need to double backslash chars in Lisp strings.)

See the Elisp manual, node [Regexp Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html), which tells you that **`\sC`** matches a character with *syntax class* **`C`**.
And see node [Syntax Class Table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html), which tells you that **`<`** designates the *comment-start syntax class*.

So `\s<` matches a comment-start character.